# Is there a way to edit nodes on an Antlr ParseTree?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am recursively traversing an antlr parse tree and I want to edit the text of TerminalNodes in the tree. I want to be able to do this for any ParseTree and I don't want to write a specific Visitor for each ParseTree I may encounter.

I have looked through The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference and seen that antlr doesn't have any direct support for tree rewriting. I am looking for any possible workarounds or alternative solutions.

```
private void editTree(ParseTree tree){

    for(int i = 0; i < tree.getChildCount();i++){

        ParseTree child = tree.getChild(i);
        if(child instanceof TerminalNode){

             //Edit child's text

        } else {

            editTree(child);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TerminalNode` has a member `getSymbol()`, which returns the lexed token. This is usually a `CommonToken` instance, which allows to set the text and other properties like line number, type etc. `ParseTree.getText()` does nothing else but asking the symbol to provide the text (which in turn is what you can set or what comes from the input stream).

Comment: I always thought `CommonToken` also didn't have `setXXX` methods. Good to know it does.